# Resolve promises one after another for previewing image on upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with image upload, you can see demo [here](https://codepen.io/ChicagoJostik/pen/mdVNEPB). I have simple html:

```
<input type="file" id="files" multiple>
<div class="preview"></div>
```

When user choose images to upload, he can see a preview of what he is uploading.

My problem is when user choose a lot of images, in preview the order of that images will be not correct, because image can have different sizes and etc., that's why the order is not correct.

So I tried `promises` and `await`. But I still can't make each promise be resolved one by one.

My js:

```
$("#files").on("change", previewFiles);

async function previewFiles() { //<-- prefix with async

    var preview = $('.preview');
    var files   = $(this)[0].files;
    preview.empty();
    function readAndPreview(file) {

        return new Promise(resolve => { //<-- reader func now returns promise...
            
            if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
              
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = event => {
                    const conta = $('<div></div>').addClass("preview__image");
                    const img = $('<img>');
                    img.attr('src', event.target.result);
                    img.attr('title', file.name);
                    img.appendTo(conta);
                    conta.appendTo( preview );
                    resolve(); //...which is resolved once onload is complete
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }

        });

    }
  
    //now let's have a master promise that waits for the sub-promises to resolve
    await Promise.all([...files].map(file => readAndPreview(file)));

}
```

Try to upload 10 images and open your console, you will see that the order of `FileList` is as supposed to be, but in preview images' order is mixed.

I saw questions maybe similar to mine, but I can't understand how can I get their answers and use for my code.

Sorry for my English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `files.map(readAndPreview)`  does call `readAndPreview` 10 times at once, starting 10 concurrent reads and creating 10 promises, then `Promise.all` waits for all of them to have finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is when user choose a lot of images, in preview the order of that images will be not correct

You don't need to read in the files sequentially to fix that. Just add the image elements to the DOM in the right order, regardless of the order in which the files finish being read.

```
async function readAndPreview(file) {
    if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) return;
    const conta = $('<div></div>').addClass("preview__image");
    conta.appendTo( preview );
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Do this immediately before starting the async read
    const { result } = await new Promise(resolve => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = event => {
            resolve(event.target);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
    const img = $('<img>');
    img.attr('src', result);
    img.attr('title', file.name);
    img.appendTo(conta);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ And when the image is loaded, show it in the right slot
}
```